# Runtime Error when calling userform with listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

hope you can help me out here, because I really can't see the error.

I'm trying to create a Userform with a listbox, where the user can choose values from an array. The code for the array is below:

```
Dim arrayData   As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Row_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow2 As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
lastRow2 = sh.Columns(45).Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Set arrayData = sh.Range("AS2:AS" & lastRow2)

arArray = sh.Range("AS2:AS" & lastRow2)

Row_Count = arrayData.Rows.Count

   
For i = 1 To Row_Count

  
    arArray(i, 45) = Cells(i, 45).Value

Next i
```

This works perfectly. Now I'm initializing the Userform:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()



Auswertung.Lst_Tabellen.List.Clear


Auswertung.Lst_Tabellen.List = arArray


End Sub
```

But everytime I'm trying to call the userform "Auswertung", I get the error "Runtime Error 424: Object Required". Can you guys see the issue?

```
Public Sub Call_Userform()

Auswertung.Show


End Sub
```

The Debugger marks the line "Auswertung.Show", when I run the code.

Comment: You are using `arArray` in the `UserForm_Initialize()` but where are you populating itin that event?

Comment: Where is `arArray` variable declared? Is it `Public` and declared at a standard module level? As Siddharth Rout asked, where is it populated? Instead of the procedure which "works perfectly", you may simple use: `arArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("AS2:AS" & lastRow2).value`. The code should only calculate `lastRow2`. This simple way will be OK: `lastRow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Cells(rows.count, 45).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: `arArray` is declared in the first module as `Public arArray As Variant`

Comment: That is ok but where are you populating it? Also when the debugger marks the line "Auswertung.Show", press F8 and step through each line. Finally tell us which line gives us the error?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by where I'm populating it? The array is defined in another sub called "Import_CSV". There I'm sorting an imported csv file. The array is a list of possible data sets, that the user can choose for further evaluation. 
So the Debugger works until the line : `Auswertung.Lst_Tabellen.List = arArray` in the UserForm_Initialize sub. Then it stops and jumps back to `Auswertung.Show`

Comment: You need to populate the array inside `UserForm_Initialize()`  Also change `Auswertung.Lst_Tabellen.List.Clear` to `Lst_Tabellen.Clear` and `Auswertung.Lst_Tabellen.List = arArray` to `Lst_Tabellen.List = arArray`

Comment: see the answer that i posted. run that and tell me what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, you need to populate the array inside `UserForm_Initialize()`

Here is an example. To test this, relace your `UserForm_Initialize` with the below code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim arRange As Range
    Dim arData As Variant
    
    '~~> Set your worksheet here
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in column AS
        lRow = .Range("AS" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Identify your range
        Set arRange = .Range("AS2:AS" & lRow)
        
        '~~> Get the data into an array. This will be a 2D array
        arData = arRange.Value2
    End With
    
    With Lst_Tabellen
        .Clear
        '~~> Transpose to get 0-based array
        .List = Application.Transpose(arData)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The array is now inside the listbox and I can choose which data to select.

Comment: So is your query sorted?

Comment: Well the next step would be, to sort the datatable depending on the selected items in the listbox, then copy some columns from the sorted raw data into a new sheet, make two charts and save the charts as well as the copied columns as 3 different files.

Comment: So your query is sorted and for the additional questions, please ask a new question

Comment: Thanks a lot.! It solved my problem. Now I have a nice listbox with the array data

Answer (score -2):

as you wrote, arArray is Variant

arArray = sh.Range("AS2:AS" & lastRow2) --> arArray is a one dimensional array

...

arArray(i, 45) = Cells(i, 45).Value --> arArray becomes a 2 dimensional array

...

Auswertung.Lst_Tabellen.List = arArray --> result unknown

Pls check the above, is it what you really want?

Comment: I see. But isn't an array always two-dimensional even if you use only one column? I mean you need the number of rows (1st. dimension) and the number of columns(2nd. dimension) in order to describe an array correctly?

Comment: No, arrays can be 1,2,3 etc dimensional depending on your declaration. see more : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays

Comment: @Apafey - Assigning (more than 1 cell in) column values to a datafield array (like e.g. `arArray = sh.Range("AS2:AS" & lastRow2)` in column AS) always results in a *1-based* **2-dim array**